# How to animate col resize in bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a layout structure like a row with two columns, at the page start i should see only one column with full screen width, so i set it to `col-sm-12` while once an event is triggered i have to show the right side column with column set to `col-sm-4` and the main column from `col-sm-12` should become `col-sm-8`.

So the layout looks like this and i've made an example that when the col-sm-12 is clicked i'd show the other column:

```js
$('.main').on('click', function() {
  $('.main').removeClass('col-sm-12')
  $('.main').addClass('col-sm-8')
  $('.side').removeClass('d-none')
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  background-color: #ff23;
}

.side {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="container-fluid h-100">

  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-sm-12 main">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 d-none side">

    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

At this how could i animate the column width change from col-sm-12 to col-sm-8?
i would do something like the hidden column will push the other by stretching it or any other fancy animation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the transition css property should do the thing, but I am not sure. Try to set:
`div[class*="col-"] { transition: .3s ease; }` and let me know.

Comment: yea the animation is that what i was looking for, but during it the col-sm-4 is shown below the col-sm-12 until it's start resize

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pygacfbv/ here you could see what happens.. when the transition starts the side column appears at bottom and the whole screen looks buggy at that point

Comment: https://hatebin.com/fvqlcocbov this code works for me, but there's a .4s second delay until the side panel shows. If it is a problem, I will try to find another solution.

Comment: that's way better but is it still possible to do a transation like the .side comes from right to left? as with ease first the main column get stretched and the side only appears after the removeClass('d-none') and that's a bit ugly [https://i.gyazo.com/95993aa1a66569c19de13d68b1598979.gif](here)

Comment: I am not sure if it's with bootstrap's predefined values possible, but I will try to fix it.

Comment: Is this effect alright for you? https://gyazo.com/7a1bd5afc450efdcbe7b0330f54b2a35

Comment: that looks cool to, but i was more thinking about https://i.gyazo.com/263b1e147f580171505de614bc6bc1b2.gif (the side comes in and stretch the main)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228295/discussion-between-jozpac-and-igor-mytyuk).